# Signin Login System in Nuxt, Axios and Feathers

Tags: database, authentication, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I created a system of login and signup in nuxt, and the system get the database data, i create one 'for' and 'if' to verify if have someone logged, and i have a code to redirect to logged page if the conditional be true, but this dosn't worked like i thinked.

```
<script>
 import Logo from '~components/Logo.vue'
 import axios from 'axios'
 export default {
  components: {
   Logo
  },
  data () {
   return { test: [] }
  },
  mounted () {
   axios.get('http://localhost:3030/users').then((res) => { this.test = 
   res.data.data })
   for (let y of this.test) { if (y.loged) { location.href = 
  'http://localhost:3000/home' } }
     }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why, but i got the resolution for my problem, this is the answer 
    
    `<script>
    import Logo from '~components/Logo.vue'
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
    components: {
      Logo
    },
    data () {
      return { test: [], x: true }
    },
    async mounted () {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:3030/users').then((res) => { this.test = 
     res.data.data })
      for (let y of this.test) { if (y.loged) { location.href = 
    'http://localhost:3000/home' } else { this.x = false } }
     }
   }
   </script>`